# Uilabel and a Tablecell

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, uitableview

A small issue i created a custom UITablecell but in the cell it's need to parse data so i connected `IBOutlet UILabel *One;` to an UILabel but when i'm doing

One.text = @"Lorem..."; an error show's up i imported the UITablecell.h in mijn viewController.

```
**Use of undeclared identifier 'One'**
```

/

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

       ViewControllerCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {

            NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ViewControllerCell" owner:nil options:nil];

            for (UIView *view in views) {
                if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
                {
                    cell = (ViewControllerCell*)view;
                }


            }

        }
One.text = @"Lorem...";
            return cell;
    }
```

Comment: @Paul.s it's an UILabel connected in Interfacebuiler in > ViewControllerCell

Comment: Yeah but where are you actually using it in your code? There is no reference in the code yo have posted...

Comment: One.text = @"Lorem...";  in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 1):

In this case your instance of your custom `UITableViewCell` class will be `cell`, so you'll need to access it like this

```
cell.One.text = @"Lorem..";
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to Typecast the tableViewCell to your Custom Cell.

```
{
  YourCustomCell *objCustomCell=(YourCustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathForThatRow];
  objCustomCell.One.text=@"YourDesiredstringvalue";
}
```